# Angular2-signaturepad used with angular gives module not found error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using [angular2-signaturepad](https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-signaturepad) in my ionic angular app. It was compiling and working till a month back.
Now when it compiles it gives below two errors

`error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad' or its corresponding type declarations.`

`error TS2305: Module '"../../../../node_modules/angular2-signaturepad/angular2-signaturepad"' has no exported member 'SignaturePadModule'.`

On checking the build logs,The one that errored has 
`Compiling angular2-signaturepad : es2015 as esm2015`

the build that worked had
`[21:50:13]: ▸ Compiling angular2-signaturepad : main as commonjs`

I have tried to add a postinstall step in package.json for ngcc to compile all possible options,

`"postinstall": "ngcc --tsconfig tsconfig.json",`
It now compiled below

```
[20:05:34]: ▸ Compiling angular2-signaturepad : esm2015 as esm2015
[20:05:34]: ▸ Compiling angular2-signaturepad : main as umd
```

Build still gave same two errors.

I am using ionic with angular 10.
I feel like I am missing something basic and simple. Appreciate any help with this!

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did you or anyone found what is happening here?

Comment: try downgrading or changing angular2-signaturepad version to 2.11.0.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-signaturepad/issues/105 change your import as below.

```
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';
```

to

```
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad';
```